# Получение элемента из значения в JSON

Tags: java, json

Как получить значение элемента "number1" из JSON

```
 String json ={"id":1,"result": 
 [{"id": {"number1": "25","text1":"abcdef"},"name1":"Ivan"},
  {"id2": {"number2": "25","text2":"abcdef"}, "name2":"Ivan"}, 
  {"id3": {"number3": "25","text3":"abcdef"}, "name3":"Ivan"};
```

Пытаюсь так:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray data = obj1.getJSONArray("result");
JSONObject obj2= data.getJSONObject(1);
```

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Это какая библиотека используется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
obj1
 .getJSONArray("result")
 .getJSONObject(0)
 .getJSONObject("id")
 .getString("number1")
```

Comment: Нумерация с нуля начинается. Так что либо `getJSONObject(0)`, либо дальше имена свойств надо исправить.

Comment: спасибо. только все работает если предпоследнюю строчку удалить.

Comment: @andreycha: Да, конечно, спасибо большое за подсказку!